# Foreign key returns nulls with JSON

Tags: json, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have two models and when i try to add a new file the file_id is null.No error message it works fine except that null. How can I fix that?

Customer :

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Builder
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    private String CustomerName;

    private String email;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<File> File = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

File :

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Builder
@Entity
@Table(name = "file")
public class File implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    
    private String file_name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="customer_id")
    private Customer Customer;

  }
```

Repository :

```
@Repository
public interface FileRepository extends JpaRepository <File,Integer> {

   
}
```

FileDTO :

```
@Data
public class FileDTO {

    private String file_name;
    private Customer customer;
```

CustomerDTO:

```
@Data
public class CustomerDTO {

    private String customernamesurname;
    private String email;
    private Customer customer;
}
```

I think problem is in mapper class. I want to add integer.
FileMapper :

```
public class FileMapper {

    public static FileDTO toDto(File file){
        File DTO fileDTO = new FileDTO();
        fileDTO.setFile_name(file.getFile_name());
        fileDTO.setCustomer(file.getCustomer());



        return fileDTO;

    }

    public static File toEntity(FileDTO fileDTO){
        File file = new File();
        file.setFile_name(fileDTO.getFile_name());
        file.setCustomer(fileDTO.getCustomer());


        return file;

    }
```

CustomerMapper:

```
public class CustomerMapper {

    public static CustomerDTO toDto(Customer customer){
        CustomerDTO customerDTO = new CustomerDTO();
        customerDTO.setCustomernamesurname(customer.getCustomernamesurname());
        customerDTO.setEmailcustomer.getEmail());



        return customerDTO;

    } 

    public static Customer toEntity(CustomerDTO customerDTO){
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        customer.setCustomernamesurname(customerDTO.getCustomernamesurname());
        customer.setEmail(customerDTO.getEmail());



        return customer;

    }
}
```

Controller :

```
  @PostMapping(path = "/addFile")
    public boolean addFile(@RequestBody FileDTO File) {
     return FileService.addFile(FileMapper.toEntity(file));
    }
```

FileImplemantion :

```
   @Override
    public boolean addFile(File file) {
        File save = fileRepository.save(file);

        if (save == null)

            return false;
        return true;


    }
```

PostgreSql :

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS customer CASCADE;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS user CASCADE;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS file CASCADE;

CREATE TABLE customer(
                        id INT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
                        customernamesurname VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
                        email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL


);

CREATE TABLE user(
    id INT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    user_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    user_password VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE file(
                          id INT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
                          file_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
                          customer_id INT,
                          FOREIGN KEY (customer_id) REFERENCES customer (id) 
);
```

I want to add File with JSON Content and use `customer_id` as foreign key. But `customer_id` returns null when I add file.

It works fine with customer. But I want only add file like these :

```
{ 
"file_name": "Test", 
"customer_id": 2 
}
```

It adds name but customer_id is null with that concept

Answer (score 0):

- You need change FileDTO:

```java
@Data
public class FileDTO {
    @JsonProperty("file_name")
    private String fileName;

    @JsonProperty("customer_id")
    private int customerId;
}
```

- Get customer by Id and set for File Enity

```java
@PostMapping(path = "/addFile")
    public boolean addFile(@RequestBody FileDTO file) {
        Customer customer = customerRepository.findById(file.getCustomerId())
                .orElseThrow(EntityNotFoundException::new);

        return fileService.addFile(FileMapper.toEntity(file, customer));
    }
```

```java
public class FileMapper {
    public static File toEntity(FileDTO fileDTO, Customer customer) {
        File file = new File();
        file.setFile_name(fileDTO.getFileName());
        file.setCustomer(customer);
        return file;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes it works fine with that. I want to add like these.{
"file_name": "Test",
"customer_id": 2
} It adds name but customer_id is null

Comment: oh, you need to change the DTO(add customer_id) and when you pass in the customer ID, you need to get it from database and set it back to the File Entity

Comment: I'm gettin an error : Non-static method 'findById(ID)' cannot be referenced from a static context